# Solaris 11 hostname

Tags: solaris, hostname

I'm new with Solaris. I cloned a Solaris 11 machine and now I'm trying to change it so that it gets the hostname and DNS name from a DHCP client.
I tried following the instructions here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/VDIpier/entry/solaris_11_changing_the_hostname
but when reconnecting to the console I get the old hostname.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: yes, it's a virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're just seeing an unchanged /etc/issue or something like that? When you log in again, and run `hostname`, does it show the new hostname? If so, that's it.

Comment: no, I still see the old hostname, even though I made the changes for nodename and loopback

Comment: @furni and does `svccfg -s system/identity:node listprop config` show the new hostname?

Comment: reboot solved all my problems